# How can I RegEx declared but uninstantiated JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, regex

Take a look at the following JavaScript:

```
let shouldBeReplaced10, shouldBeReplaced11
var shouldBeReplaced12, shouldBeReplaced13

let shouldBeReplaced10,shouldBeReplaced11, shouldBeReplaced12, shouldBeReplaced49

let shouldBeReplaced10,
    shouldBeReplaced11


let shouldBeReplaced17
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will capture all the variable names so I can replace them with other strings. This is what I'm up to so far:

```
/(?:let|var)\s+(\w|,|\s)*/gm
```

As you may guess, it's not working - it essentially captures the entire text, and returns the last character (`7`) as my match. Usually I'm ok with regex, but in this case I just can't seem to conceptualize what my next step is.

Any ideas?

PS: I know there are more ways of declaring variables than this. I'm already capturing those with a different regex. This particular declaration - declaring without a value - escapes the previous regex.

PPS: To be clear, this is a 'for fun' project. I'm trying to replace variable and function names with silly alternatives. 'Use an existing obfuscator' and such answers are thus not relevant.

Comment: You're writing regex to parse JavaScript?

Comment: How would you do it? Regex is the only way I know of. (to be clear, my overall intention is essentially the same as an obfuscator - replace all function and variable names with different values. It's not _actually_ an obfuscator but it's a decent analogy.)

Comment: How would I do **what**?  You haven't explained at all what exactly it is you're trying to do.  My assumption was that you were refactoring old code and your IDE had a regex search/replace feature.  My suggestion was going to be to use your IDE's built-in language parsing features instead.  Now you say you're writing your own obfuscator, for which my suggestion would be to use an existing one.  This is dangerous territory, there are a lot of edge cases.  You can't simply replace variable names in a dynamic language like JavaScript.  What are you trying to actually accomplish?

Comment: I have explained exactly what I'm trying to accomplish - `replace all function and variable names with different values`. I didn't say I was writing my own obfuscator, I said it was similar to an obfuscator in that regard. But in the interest of total clarity, this is a 'for fun' project. I want to replace variable and function names with silly replacements. `You can't simply replace variable names in a dynamic language like JavaScript.`. Clearly you can, otherwise there would be no such things as obfuscators, no?

Comment: The obfuscators perform very careful analysis of the code to determine what can be replaced and what can't... and side effects are still introduced!  You have to remember that JavaScript can inspect itself.  If I call `toString()` on a function, I can effectively get its source.  If that source is obfuscated, I have now introduced a side effect.  Usually this isn't a problem, but it certainly can be.  Consider another case where you obfuscate a class that was exporting variables for code external to it.  You start to see the problem.

Comment: If you're going to do this successfully, you need a JavaScript tokenizer.  Start here:  https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/master/lib/parse-js.js  And, next time you post a question, explain what it is you're trying to accomplish along with how you're attempting to do it.

Comment: I did. It's not my fault you didn't read the question. But I thank you for the link and responses.

Comment: I read your question.  You didn't mention this, "for fun" learning project until a comment later.  You should have put that in your question to provide context for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?:(?<=^|let|var) +|(?<=,) *)(\w+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC9ZKz/2/)

Comment: This fails on code like `function (a, b) {}`.  It finds the `b` but not the `a`.  Depending on the desired outcome, I think it should find both or neither.